# VSCode on Mac doesn't take inputs, shows "cmdand cmdand quote>" instead

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I use Visual studio code for coding competitions and to practice for it, I have to do questions which require me to input certain things and get an output for that thing.
The problem is that whenever I run the code (C++ by the way), the terminal just shows: `cmdand cmdand quote>`and whenever I type something in and hit enter, it just goes to a new line and says the same thing. Does anyone know if there's just something wrong with my computer? Or is it something else?

Edit: To respond to Alan Birtles, this is the shortest I can do.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int N;
    cin >> N;
    string winner, person;
    int max_bid = 0, bid;
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        cin >> person;
        cin >> bid;
        if (bid > max_bid)
        {
            max_bid = bid;
            winner = person;

        }
    }
    cout << winner << endl;

}
```

It's meant to solve this problem: https://dmoj.ca/problem/ccc21j2
I'm not sure how exactly to explain it, but when I press the triangle run button, this is what shows up:[Terminal Image after run attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfKrN.png).

Comment: Please show a [mre], what code are you trying to run? How did you compile it? How are you trying to run it?

Comment: @AlanBirtles check the latest update. Unsure what you mean by how I compiled it. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Did you input correctly? Input the given test case completely and tell what happens

Comment: @risingStark It doesn't let you input anything. If you type anything in and hit enter, it just goes to a new line with the same "cmdand cmdand quote>" at the start.

Comment: Your compiler command looks odd, i guess whatever you used to create can't handle spaces in file names

Answer (score -1):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEdRj.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TB9dj.png)

Hi buddy, I also encounter you the same problem.
First you need to check the name of the file, my file name "Hello's-world.c" is this problem before the occurrence.

If it is not a file name, check the C / C ++ file of VSCode, uninstall it and reinstall it, or check the GCC version installed in this unit! Please forgive my junk English, I use the translation of Googl! Maybe help you!